# Converting user to an offline user?

Tags: java, performance, caching, memcached

Heyho,

I'm currently working on a **user system** for a game server. So my problem is that there will be a lot of users, but I also need information about them when they are **offline**.

The 2 versions of the user should look like this:

**Online version**: *username, id, lastLogin, metadata, gui stuff...*

**Offline version**: *username, id, metadata*

I'm using google guava to cache the users and after the cache is "full" I want to **downgrade** the user to an offline user, which takes less memory.
My question is now, how I could achive this. Is there maybe a better cache system as *google guava*, which support's such a behavior?

I really depend on an **offline version** of my users, because they are needed very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have 2 version of `user`, you should have two classes : `User` and `OnlineProperties`. The user has variable : `OnlineProperties onlineProperties = null`

The user should have methods `goOnline` which creates instance of `OnlineProperties` and add it to the user and `goOffline` which is doing simple `onlineProperties = null`

Comment: Thanks for your respons, you gave me an idea :D Maybe I can integrate this into my extension/metadata system.